# Why I had an error, inside angular when I start the test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, unit-testing, intellij-idea

Than I add this:

```
beforeEach(module('tabQuestionsApp'));
```

inside derictive test I has an error:

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\tek.WebIde80\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijRunner.js --karmaPackageDir=C:\Users\tek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma --serverPort=8080 --urlRoot=/

minErr/<@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js:78:12
loadModules/<@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js:3906:15
forEach@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js:325:9
loadModules@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js:3872:5
createInjector@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js:3812:11
workFn@D:/OpenServer/domains/project/web/js/appcrm/tab_questions/app/scripts/resources/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2244:46

Process finished with exit code 0

my app - init:

```
angular.module('tabQuestionsApp', ['ngSelectable','angularFileUpload','ngCkeditor','ngSanitize']);
```

karma included files:

```
files: [
  'app/scripts/resources/ng-file-upload-shim/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/angular/angular.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/lodash/dist/lodash.js',
  'app/scripts/resources/ngSelectable/src/ngSelectable.js',
  'app/views/*.html',
  'app/scripts/app.js',
  'app/scripts/directives/tagSearch.js',
  'test/spec/directives/tagSearch.js'

     ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass function as argument to `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('yourModuleName');
})
```